# identify similar rows and delete one with different predicate

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have an Oracle table with the following columns in it:

ID (PK)
Column_1
Column_2
Column_3
Column_4 (with only value as 0 or 1)

I need to find matching rows in the same table by Column_1, Column_2, Column_3 and delete all matching rows where Column_4 is not 0

How do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete from table_x
where exists
  (select * from table_x t2
    where t2.id!=table_x.id
      and t2.column_1=table_x.column_1
      and t2.column_2=table_x.column_2
      and t2.column_3=table_x.column_3)
    and table_x.column_4!=0
```

The t2.id!=table_x.id is necessary so a record does not match itself.

Note that with the above query, if you have two rows that match on columns 1, 2, and 3, and both have column 4 != 0, it will delete both, because both have a matching record and both and column_4!=0. By a strictly literal reading of what you said above, I think that's what you want. If that's not what you meant, you may need to alter the query some.

As with any query that can potentially delete huge numbers of records, I'd make a copy of the table to test on or have some other back up plan in case the results are not what you expect. :-)